# Why does NashornScriptEngineFactory haven't the possibility to get a ScriptEngine with only ClassFilter and args?

Tags: javascript, java-8, nashorn, scriptengine

I am currently using Nashorn in a project and I would like to create a `ScriptEngine` from `NashornScriptEngineFactory` with only a `ClassFilter` in order to secure my script to avoid unexpected call to some libraries. And I would like also add arguments to the factory (here `--strict` in order to execute all javascript function in strict mode).

I found only these prototypes in `NashornScriptEngineFactory` :

```
public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine()
public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine(final String... args)
public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine(final ClassFilter classFilter)
public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine(final ClassLoader appLoader)
public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine(final String[] args, final ClassLoader appLoader)
public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine(final String[] args, final ClassLoader appLoader, final ClassFilter classFilter)
```

I wonder why there is no prototype :

```
public ScriptEngine getScriptEngine(final String[] args, final ClassFilter classFilter)
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Just use the ClassLoader instance for the class that's calls `getScriptEngine()`. Like, just pass `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`.

Comment: @Pointy It seems to work like a charm. Thanks a lot. I let you answer the question if you want. I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal, simple situation, you can generally just use the class loader of the class that's making the call to get a `ScriptEngine` instance. That is, you can just pass

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader()
```

(or explicitly reference the class by name). Just pass that to the three-argument `getScriptEngine()` method.

Now, in not-so-normal, not-so-simple situations, where you have multiple class loaders to worry about (sometimes an issue in a servlet container or something like an Ant task for example), then where you get the class loader from might make a difference. If you really are in a situation like that, then (A) good luck and (B) hopefully you'll have enough context to know what to pass.